# Flyway Migrate - External Table Create Throwing ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle, table, flyway

We use flyway in our company to make changes to the various regions. The guy who set all this up is unfortunately left the company so I don't have anyone really to run this past.

I have a bit of SQL that creates an External Oracle table and if I run the SQL manually in PLSQL it completes fine so the issue itself doesn't appear to be the SQL but more likely some issue Flyway has with some element of the SQL.

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.2.0:migrate (default-cli) on project SCV-Flyway: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateSqlException:
[ERROR] Migration V029.18__LIFP8978_CreateTable_LD_PAX_CDNIGHT_HEADER.sql failed
[ERROR] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] SQL State  : 42000
[ERROR] Error Code : 922
[ERROR] Message    : ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
[ERROR] Location   : src/scripts/V029.18__LIFP8978_CreateTable_LD_PAX_CDNIGHT_HEADER.sql (C:\Development\Java\scv\Database\SCV\src\scripts\V029.18__LIFP8978_CreateTable_LD_PAX_CDNIGHT_HEADER.sql)
[ERROR] Line       : 1
[ERROR] Statement  : CREATE TABLE LD_PAX_CDNIGHT_HEADER
[ERROR] (
[ERROR]   record_code      VARCHAR2(1),
[ERROR]   record_date      DATE
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
[ERROR] (
[ERROR]   TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
[ERROR]   DEFAULT DIRECTORY EPAXUS_PRD_DATALOAD
[ERROR]   ACCESS PARAMETERS
[ERROR]   (
[ERROR]     RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
[ERROR]     NODISCARDFILE
[ERROR]     NOLOGFILE
[ERROR]     LOAD WHEN ( record_code = '1')
[ERROR]     FIELDS MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
[ERROR]     (
[ERROR]            record_code           POSITION(1:1)     CHAR,
[ERROR]            record_date           POSITION(3:12)    DATE'DD/MM/YYYY'
[ERROR]     )
[ERROR]   )
[ERROR]   LOCATION (EPAXUS_PRD_DATALOAD:'PAX-CDNIGHT.TXT')
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
[ERROR]
```

Has anyone come across anything like this before or can spot what possibly my error might be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Flyway didn't like the date format being directly after the type, needed a space between them:

```
DATE 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

Hopefully helps someone else down the line...